# Java (Tomcat) websocket parameters from client side

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I need to pass some parameters from javascript client to the Java endpoint in Tomcat.

With Tomcat you can *annote* your java class with `@ServerEndpoint(value="/websocket")` and then this class will be the endpoint for your websocket.

I.e. every time when a javascript calls `new WebSocket("ws://localhost/websocket")` your annoted class will be instantiated.

Now I want to pass a short string parameter (or int, does not really matter) from the javascript client side to my annoted class <s>preferably</s> during instantiation (i.e. in the constructor).

How shall I do this?

I have thought of putting it into the url, but then I would need to do something else instead of the annotation thus it does not feel too safe.

Comment: You can show what you have tried?

Comment: I can do it with `@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket/{clientId}")`. But is there any way to not include the parameter in the url?

Answer (score 0):

you could pass it as a header and Java tomcat endpoint which is exposing web socket has to read the header and set it to user properties map of endpoint config
Example

public class WsHandShakeInterceptor extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {

```
@Override
public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig sec, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response) {
    super.modifyHandshake(sec, request, response);

    setUserHeadersAsProps(sec, request);
}

private void setUserHeadersAsProps(ServerEndpointConfig sec, HandshakeRequest request) {
    Map<String, List<String>> headers = request.getHeaders();
    if (headers != null) {
        List<String> userNameHeader = headers.get(HeadersConst.OIDC_CLAIM_USERNAME);
        if (userNameHeader != null && !userNameHeader.isEmpty()) {
            sec.getUserProperties().put(HeadersConst.X_FORWARDED_USER, userNameHeader.get(0));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).